# Creating low memory conditions on IPad device

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory

I  want  to test  the   behaviour  of an  app repeatedly  at  low  memory  conditions. I want these  low  memory  states  to be  reproducable.So  runnly  lots  of  websites in the  background is  not  enough.

I've  read the   similar  post  on

[How to test memory low condition on real iphone/ipad device (not simulator)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200936/how-to-test-memory-low-condition-on-real-iphone-ipad-device-not-simulator)

Has  anyone  created a  background app with this  functionality?

Saving the  memory  state  to  file  would  be  also useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, iOS will kill the background app before it notifies you that there is not enough memory. So you have to consume the memory within you app.

A way would be to repeatedly allocate memory over a amount of time (allocating it all at once will force iOS to kill your app afair).